# Prevent recursive trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, recursion

How to prevent recursive execution of trigger?  Let's say I want to construct a "tree-able" description on chart of account. So what I do is when a new record is inserted/updated, I update the the parent record's `down_qty`, so this would trigger the update trigger recursively.

Right now, my code is ok - I put this on `UPDATE` trigger's first line:

```
-- prevents recursive trigger
if new.track_recursive_trigger <> old.track_recursive_trigger then
    return new;
end if;
```

And this is the sample code from my trigger when I need to update the parent record's qty:

```
update account_category set 
    track_recursive_trigger = track_recursive_trigger + 1, -- i put this line to prevent recursive trigger
    down_qty = down_qty - (old.down_qty + 1)
where account_category_id = m_parent_account;
```

I'm thinking if there's a way in PostgreSQL to detect recursive trigger without introducing a new field, something analogous to MSSQL's `trigger_nestlevel`.

**[EDIT]**

I loop inside the tree, I need to bubble up the `down_qty` of each `account_category` back to its root.  For example, I insert a new account category, it needs to increment the `down_qty` of its parent `account_category`, likewise when I change the account category's parent `account_category`, I need to decrement the `down_qty` of `account_category`'s previous parent `account_category`.  Though I think it can, I'm not letting PostgreSQL do the recursive trigger.  I used MSSQL before where the trigger recursive depth level is limited only up to `16` levels.

Comment: I think you should explain in a bit more details, because as far as I can see there is no danger of recursive call in here unless you have either: record which is its own parent, or loops in your tree (which is not tree then).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In pg, it's up to you to track trigger recursion.

> If a trigger function executes SQL
> commands then these commands might
> fire triggers again. This is known as
> cascading triggers. There is no direct
> limitation on the number of cascade
> levels. It is possible for cascades to
> cause a recursive invocation of the
> same trigger; for example, an INSERT
> trigger might execute a command that
> inserts an additional row into the
> same table, causing the INSERT trigger
> to be fired again. It is the trigger
> programmer's responsibility to avoid
> infinite recursion in such scenarios.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/trigger-definition.html

Comment: Sorry but have to downvote as the question asked **how** to prevent recursion. This answer states the user needs to track trigger recursion, which the question already acknowledges, and is what is being asked how to solve.

Answer (score 126):

This is what I do in PostgreSQL 9.2, although I must admit I did not find this approach documented. There is a function `pg_trigger_depth()` [documented here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-info.html), which I use to differentiate between original and nested calls in the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_taxonomic_positions
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF taxonomic_position
ON taxon_concepts
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_taxonomic_positions()
```

Comment: Brilliant! Unfortunately, this function is not present in 9.1 :(. I wonder if there is a replacement for it...

Comment: Lifesaver. Confirmed it works on 9.4 like a charm. Someone should help this make its way to the documentation. As far as I've looked, haven't seen any meaningful examples on the trigger `WHEN (condition)` clause. This definitely qualifies.

Comment: It work, but pay some attention because that function is not to measure recursive. If other trigger originate the actual trigger, that function will produce 1 instead 0.

Answer (score 2):

At the beggining of the definition of the trigger you can disable triggers on that particular table, and reenable them at the end (and make sure an exception doesn't terminate the execution before expected!). This has many deep holes, but may work for some light implementations. Notice that for this implementation, you will also need priviliges to disable triggers.

Comment: this doesn't work, because: cannot ALTER TABLE "trigger_table" because it is being used by active queries in this session

Answer (score 2):

To avoid unbounded recursion, see  [my answer  here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14092775/905902). As others have commented, if your data structure is a true tree (the root(s) will have no parent(s)) and the recursion will **always stop** at the root(s). For *nodes* with only one parent *pointer*, the only way for unbounded recursion would be if there were loops present. (the method in my link will visit any node *at most* once)