# How to avoid recursion in a trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a problem with recursion in a trigger.

I have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
   task int4 NOT NULL,
   first_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   last_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (task, cli_id_number)
);
```

When I insert the values:

```
(123, name, last)
```

i want to automatically insert these values as well:

```
(321, name, last)
```

I do this in the following way, but apparently the trigger is recursive and after the first recursion it tries to insert the previously inserted value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_task() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  IF new.task = '123' AND (
     SELECT cant FROM (
       SELECT name, task, count(*) AS cant
       FROM client_task
       WHERE name = NEW.name AND task = NEW.task
       GOUP BY 1,2
       HAVING count(*) <= 1
     ) t) = 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO client_task(task, name, last_name)
    VALUES('321', NEW.task, NEW.name, NEW.last_name);
    RETURN NEW;
  ELSE 
    IF NEW.task = '321' AND (
      SELECT cant FROM (
        SELECT name, task, count(*) AS cant
        FROM client_task
        WHERE name = NEW.name AND task = NEW.task
        GROUP BY 1, 2
        HAVING count(*) <=1
      ) t) = 1 THEN
      INSERT INTO client_task(task, name, last_name)
      VALUES('123', NEW.task, NEW.name, NEW.last_name);
      RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @DavidVega según [este hilo](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish), están preparando el lanzamiento de StackOverflow en español.  Lamentablemente esta página utiliza inglés exclusivamente, por lo tanto tendrán que cerrar tu pregunta. (I'm directing the user to a thread on a supposedly upcoming Spanish StackOverflow and explaining that this site is in English only so his question will be closed.)

Answer (score 3):

Use the function `pg_trigger_depth()`. According to [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-info.html) it returns:

> current nesting level of PostgreSQL triggers (0 if not called,
> directly or indirectly, from inside a trigger)

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_task
AFTER INSERT ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_task()
```

Comment: Thanks @klin it Was very helpfull