# Postgresql trigger run non stop?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I try to work with trigger here. 
I have a relation like this :

```
salary(salaryid, userid, netsalary, reward, totalsalary)
```

So I want to update `totalsalary` everytime I insert and update (`netsalary` or `reward`), it will recount : `totalsalary = netsalary + reward`.

To do that, I made a function and a trigger :

```
CREATE FUNCTION reCount()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $function$
BEGIN 
  UPDATE salary SET totalsalary = netsalary + reward;
  RETURN NEW;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER updateTotalsalary
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON salary
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE reCount();
```

Finally, I try to test by a query insert like this :

```
INSERT INTO salary(salaryid,userid,netsalary,reward,totalsalary) 
    VALUES (1234,123, 30,2,30);
```

but it run for a long time and it seem never stop. So when a try to stop it with, I got many rows of :

> SQL statement "UPDATE salary SET totalsalary = netsalary + reward"
>   PL/pgSQL function "reCount()" line 3 at SQL statement

So what is the problem. Hope you guys can give me some suggestion?

Comment: I am just wondering if the trigger could trigger itself by the update?

Comment: Thanks user2672165, I see the problem. So after I make the query update in the function, it will do that again and again... Thank you so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent recursive trigger in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708562/prevent-recursive-trigger-in-postgresql)

Comment: You are updating ***all*** rows in the table each time you update a single row. Are you sure you want to do that? I think you actually want `new.totalsalry = new.netsalary + new.reward` instead of an `update` statement in the trigger function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTotalsalary 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON salary 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE reCount();
```

Comment: I have found another solution, I don't use UPDATE anymore but 
**NEW.totalsalary = NEW.netsalary + NEW.reward**

And it work fine!

Comment: Yes that is much better!

Comment: What if `salary` is updated from another trigger? This solution doesn't work.

Comment: "What if this and that" was not part of the question, but yes to this problem there are better solutions. I at least helped in finding the cause (see initial comment).

Answer (score 0):

this might be better than the `pg_trigger_depth() = 0` hack:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTotalsalary 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF netsalary, reward
ON salary 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE reCount();
```

> For UPDATE events, it is possible to specify a list of columns using
>   this syntax:
>
> UPDATE OF column_name1 [, column_name2 ... ]
>
> The trigger will only fire if at least one of the listed columns is
>   mentioned as a target of the UPDATE command.

though personally i'd probably go for a table without the totalsalary column and a view with it (`CREATE TABLE salary_ ...`, `CREATE VIEW salary AS SELECT ..., (salary + reward) AS totalsalary FROM salary_`).