# Prevent rucursive triggering when executing trigger function in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a trigger and a function that will update the `pricing` table. The trigger must shoot only when a new value containing 'regular' in `offer` column is inserted/updated:

```
drop trigger if exists reduced_offer on pricing;
drop function if exists offer_f();

create or replace function offer_f() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if (new.title, new.publisher,new.offer) in  --the offer already EXISTS
        (select title, publisher, offer
        from pricing)
    then
        raise notice 'exists';
        update pricing
        set price=new.price*0.9
        where title=new.title and publisher=new.publisher and period=new.period;
    else                        --the offer does NOT EXIST
        raise notice 'not exists';
        insert into pricing values
            (new.title, new.publisher, 'renew', new.period, new.price*0.9);
    end if; 

    return null;
end $$ language plpgsql;


create trigger reduced_offer 
after insert or update 
on pricing
for each row
when (new.offer='regular')
execute procedure offer_f();
```

The problem:
When I run this query:

```
insert into pricing values ('Nature', 'UCLA', 'regular', 9900, 20);
```

when I know for sure that this entry was not in `pricing` table, I get stack overflow error and this ENDLESS output (more than 20000 lines):

> NOTICE:  exists
>
> NOTICE:  exists
>
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "update pricing
>
> ```
>   set price=new.price*0.9
>
>   where title=new.title and publisher=new.publisher and
> ```
>
> period=new.period
>
> and offer='regular'"
>
> PL/pgSQL function offer_f() line 8 at SQL statement
>
> NOTICE:  exists
>
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "update pricing
>
> ```
>   set price=new.price*0.9
>
>   where title=new.title and publisher=new.publisher and
> ```
>
> period=new.period
>
> AND SO ON....

any idea what can cause this overflow?

Comment: How does the  pricing trigger know that it wasn't called due to a previous call to the pricing  trigger? Therefore it should stop?

Comment: how should I stop it after one execution per update/insert (not induced by the trigger function itself)?

Comment: I am not a postgresql person. Still, Maybe interesting? [Prevent recursive trigger in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708562/prevent-recursive-trigger-in-postgresql). I have met similar issues with other database engines.