# How to pretend ordering records just like line numbers of an editor

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

This is about storing commands in a database instead of a text file or spreadsheet.
I am looking for a solution, which mimics the behavior of line numbers in a text editor.

E.g. Given the table below with the column "Order" as the primary key, when I delete the second row (Order = 2), I would end up with a gap in the order column (1, 3), which needs to be corrected to (1, 2)

```
| Order | Command      |     | Order | Command      |     | Order | Command      |
|-------|--------------|     |-------|--------------|     |-------|--------------|
|   1   | CAM - ON     | ==> |   1   | CAM - ON     | ==> |   1   | CAM - ON     |
|   2   | Turn left    |     |   3   | Take picture |     |   2   | Take picture |
|   3   | Take picture |
```

I have already experimented with triggers. Before the record gets deleted, a trigger updates the relevant order numbers of the other records. I have also triggers to deal with appending or inserting a new record "before" an existing one.

I know the physical order on disk is different and irrelevant. So, I just manipulate the "Order" column to mimic the behaviour of line numbers.

The same works fine with updating records. E.g. if I want to "move" the "Turn left" command to the first position, implementing a trigger before update to reorder the other records does the trick too. E.g. set the order of the "Turn left" command to 1 and the trigger updates the other records first:

```
| Order | Command      |     | Order | Command      |
|-------|--------------|     |-------|--------------|
|   1   | CAM - ON     | ==> |   2   | CAM - ON     |
|   2   | Turn left    |     |   1   | Turn left    |
|   3   | Take picture |     |   3   | Take picture |
```

However, this one introduces a problem. Deleting or inserting a record triggers a procedure, which updates records, which now triggers the update procedure. This seems to make things recursive and complicated.

I tried to disable and enable the update trigger from within the other trigger procedures, but (in postgresl) this requires altering the table, which is not allowed during a query..

My question is: Is there a more straight forward solution, which covers all four CRUD Operations? Perhaps involving other data types for the order column instead of integer or completely different techniques?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9536262 ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need a trigger to achieve this. Just make the primary key deferrable, and you can remove and renumber in a single statement:

```
create table data (order_no integer not null, command text);

alter table data 
   add constraint pk_data 
   primary key (order_no) 
   deferrable initially immediate;
```

To delete a row use this:

```
with removed_row as (
  delete from data
  where ord = 1
  returning ord
)
update data
  set order_no = order_no - 1
where order_no > (select order_no from removed_row);
```

To insert a new row in the middle you can use this:

```
with new_row as (
   insert into data values (3, 'Tilt up')
   returning order_no
)
update data
  set order_no = order_no + 1
where order_no >= (select order_no from new_row);
```

Moving a row can also be done that way:

To move a row down:

```
with to_move(old_no, new_no) as (
  values (5,2)
), move_row as (   
  update data
    set order_no = new_no
  from to_move
  where order_no = old_no
)  
update data
   set order_no = order_no + 1
from to_move
where order_no >= new_no
  and order_no < old_no
;
```

And to move a row up:

```
with to_move(old_no, new_no) as (
  values (2,4)
), move_row as (   
  update data
    set order_no = new_no
  from to_move
  where order_no = old_no
)
update data
   set order_no = order_no - 1
from to_move
where order_no > old_no
  and order_no <= new_no 
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with triggers: what you are looking for is a derived value, that you can compute on the fly when needed, using `row_number()`. Also, it is generally not a good practice to play around with the primary key of a table (which is what your `order` column looks to me).

```
select
    ord original_order,
    row_number() over(order by ord) real_order,
    command
from mytable
```

You can create a view to save yourself the effort of typing the window function repeatidly:

```
create view as 
select 
    ord original_order,
    row_number() over(order by ord) real_order
    command
from mytable
```

Note that `order` is not  a wise choice for a column name, since it clashes with a reserved word. I renamed it to `ord` it the above queries.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work so well. When there is no primary key, I can end up with 5 rows with ord = 1. When I then want to insret a new record somwhere between these 5, I cannot choose anymore where exactly.

Comment: Why is there no primary key?

Comment: @joop: That is part of the difficulty. If I have 5 records and the column ord is primary key, I cannot insret a new record with say, ord = 2, because it already exists. Both ways, I don't have a complete solution yet.

Comment: You do not want to do this. NEVER under normal operations change the PK. That is the main component maintaining your data correct.  For example: Suppose you get this all worked out (questionable at best, but you do). Now the customer who placed order 3 has a problem and tells support that. Either order 3 no longer exist or worse, another order has that id? Now what do you do.  You say you want to mimic line numbers in an editor, but those line numbers do not actually exist, they are generated on the fly, but the no data changes when they do.

Comment: @Belayer: Indeed, I don't require ord to be the primary key. It should be unique, start at 1 and have no gaps. But I do need to store the information, in which order the commands are sent to my robot. This is the reason whay they have to exist and cannot be generated on the fly.

Comment: Why not have a timestamp `happened_at`, instead of your *record number* ? Plenty of gaps, and complete order!

Comment: @joop: This was actually my previous approach. But I was critisized by the experts who deliver the commands and they are right. They cannot always provide timing. E.g. there is no way you can estimate the exposure time of a camera in auto exposure mode. Could be 1micro second or 50 seconds. Additionally, we always test a procedure with real HW. After testing, we get the timing as a measurement, which is much better than the estimates anyway. So, timing estimates turned out to be a waste of time in our workflow.

Comment: You don't want an actual timestamp for the time per se, you only want absolute order. But IMHO it is a very bad idea to *shift up* some records because some other record happens to change value.

Comment: I don't see why "no gaps" is a hard requirement. If you can order by this column's value, you can always get your consecutive values by using rownum in the SELECT. I'd second the idea to use timestamps or perhaps leave large gaps for insertion without renumbering other rows.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not really a good match for a relational database - if it was me, and the number of commands is not too large, I'd just store it as a JSON or XML clob.

But if you must use relational storage, I think that having to update on the average half of all rows after each insert
is not a good design.

I'd suggest not storing the actual number, but just have the `ord` column
define a relative order. As @GMB [already wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116032/1096710), you can then use
`row_number` to get your consecutive numbers starting with 1.

To insert new rows without having to renumber existing ones, leave "holes"
in the numbering:

Let MIN and MAX be the minimum and maximum numbers you want to use in the
`ord` column. Then the very first row you insert should get

```
ord = (MIN + MAX) / 2
```

To insert a new row between two existing rows with order numbers
`o1` and `o2`, use

```
ord = (o1 + o2) / 2
```

Depending on the number of rows and number of inserts/updates you expect,
a collision (i.e. no space between `o1` and `o2`) may occur, so
you should also have a renumbering procedure for that case.
E.g. if you insert already ordered items this will very quickly
(after log(max - min) inserts).

Here's pseudocode to get the `ord` number for insertion after a given row
with `ord == o1`:

```
let next = SELECT MIN(ord) FROM commands WHERE ord > :o1
if next IS NULL then
    if o1 == MAX     then panic_or_renumber
    if o1 == MAX - 1 then MAX
    else (o1 + MAX) / 2
else
    if next == o1 + 1 then panic_or_renumber
    else (o1 + next) / 2
```

(Note that `(a + b) / 2` can overflow when using signed arithmetic. Choose your
bounds accordingly or use safer arithmetic if you need huge numbers of rows).

Answer (score 0):

My question was based on the assumption that a trigger cannot be disabled while a trigger procedure is executed.

While this is still true, [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708562/prevent-recursive-trigger-in-postgresql) shows that you can actually use the `pg_trigger_depth()` function to check the trigger depth **before** a trigger procedure is called. This way, checking against trigger depth = 0 does the trick to prevent a trigger procedure from calling an other. E.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_commands_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON commands FOR EACH ROW WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0) EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_commands();
```

Going back to the idea of using triggers has the important advantage that neither user mistakes, nor application bugs cannot corrupt the database. Therefore, I would like to share my updated solution (using postgresql version 11.6), which successfully prevented all my attempts to create invalid data so far.

I have renamed "Order" to step as advised, but stick to the step number as primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE commands (
    step integer primary key NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 CONSTRAINT positive_order CHECK (step >= 0),
    command character varying
);
ALTER TABLE commands OWNER TO kagan;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_commands()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE max_step integer;
DECLARE rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    select max(step) into max_step from commands;
    if NEW.step is null then RAISE EXCEPTION 'step must have a value'; end if;
    if NEW.step < 1 then RAISE EXCEPTION 'step (%) must be >= 1', NEW.step; end if;
    if NEW.step > max_step then RAISE EXCEPTION 'step (%) must be <= max(step) (%)', NEW.step, max_step; end if;

    -- Temporarily, move the current record at the old position "out of the way"
    -- Don't forget the other columns
    UPDATE commands set step = 0, command = NEW.command where step = OLD.step;

    if NEW.step > OLD.step then
        FOR rec IN
            select step from commands
            where step > OLD.step and step <= NEW.step
            order by step ASC
        LOOP
            UPDATE commands set step =  step - 1 where step = rec.step;
        END LOOP;
    else
        FOR rec IN
            select step from commands
            where step >= NEW.step and step < OLD.step
            order by step DESC
        LOOP
            UPDATE commands set step =  step + 1 where step = rec.step;
        END LOOP;
    end if;

    -- Put the current row back to the new position
    UPDATE commands set step = NEW.step where step = 0;
    RETURN NULL;    -- DO NOT PROCEED 
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_commands()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE max_step integer;
DECLARE rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    if NEW.step < 1 then RAISE EXCEPTION 'step (%) must be >= 1)', NEW.step; end if;

    select max(step) into max_step from commands;
    if max_step is null then
        NEW.step = 1;
    elsif NEW.step > max_step + 1 then
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'step (%) must be <= max(step) + 1 (%)', NEW.step, max_step + 1;
    else
        FOR rec IN select step from commands where step >= NEW.step order by step DESC LOOP
            UPDATE commands set step =  step + 1 where step = rec.step;
        END LOOP;
    end if;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_commands()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE rec RECORD;
BEGIN
        FOR rec IN select step from commands where step > OLD.step order by step ASC LOOP
            UPDATE commands set step =  step - 1 where step = rec.step;
        END LOOP;
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER insert_commands_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON commands FOR EACH ROW WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0) EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_commands();
CREATE TRIGGER delete_commands_trigger AFTER DELETE ON commands FOR EACH ROW WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0) EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_commands();
CREATE TRIGGER update_commands_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON Commands FOR EACH ROW WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0) EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_commands();

COPY commands (step, command) FROM stdin;
1   CAM - ON
2   Turn left
3   Take picture
\.
```